# Use historical data to build surface with limited number of points

Tags: time-series, pca, data-visualization, interpretation, dataset

Lets say I have historical surfaces of data which vary slightly during time, but keeps similiar dynamics.

I would like to use these historical data sets to estimate todays surface (given a limited number of points) using the dynamics of historical surfaces.

Does anyone have an idé to approach this? Have looked into PCA but can't establish a method that can be used.

To clearify:
1. I have data of implied volatility surfaces during time. 
2. I want to use these surfaces and calculate a new surface of returns. i.e the day to day difference for each volatility point.
3. However, i just want to use a limited number of points to build up the new "return" surface.

I have historical return surfaces with similar dynamics which can be of help.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Spatio-Temporal-Data-Noel-Cressie/dp/0471692743